# How to pass separated tfrecord datasets: trainX (images) and trainY (labels) to model.fit()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

## Problem

Due to one custom layer in my model, I need to pass the labels together with images to the model during training. So this is how I called the fit method:

```
history = model.fit((trainX,trainY),
                            trainY,
                            epochs=epochs,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            validation_data=((testX,testY), testY),
                            callbacks=callbacks,
                            shuffle=True)
```

I can train the model without problem, when trainX, trainY, testX and testY are numpy arrays.
So I thought it would work if I create tfrecords of each of them separately, load them and pass them into fit method. But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```

I understand why the error has happened, but I'm looking for a solution. My training dataset is huge and I can't load them as numpy array in memory.

I'm also aware that datasets should be passed as only one argument like:

```
history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                            epochs=epochs,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            validation_data=val_dataset,
                            callbacks=callbacks,
                            shuffle=True)
```

However, this is not useful, as I need to have labels passed to the model. So that's why I came to the idea of splitting dataset and pass it like (trainX, trainY), trainY.

Is there anyway to do what I want? I prefer tfrecords as they are fast in comparison with reading images as files from directory, and also it does not need to load the whole file at once.

## My solution

I've found a solution which now solves my problem and that is to implement a fully custom training loop using tf.GradientTape():

```py
@tf.function
def train_step(x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Here you pass arguments in your desired way
        logits = model((x,y), training=True)
        loss_value = loss_fn(y, logits)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    train_acc_metric.update_state(y, logits)
    return loss_value

# Prepare the loss function
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# Prepare the metrics.
train_acc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
val_acc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    epoch_losses = []
    for img, label in zip(trainX, trainY):
        loss_value = train_step(img, label)
        epoch_losses.append(loss_value.numpy())
    
    # Display metrics at the end of each epoch.
    train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
    train_epoch_loss = np.mean(epoch_losses)
    
    # Reset training metrics at the end of each epoch
    train_acc_metric.reset_states()
```

Comment: Have you added two inputs in your model? How is your model's architecture?

Comment: Yes, the model works perfectly. As I mentioned, I have no problem if I use numpy arrays for training. The problem is passing tf.data.Dataset to model.fit()

Comment: I guess, I could use gradientTape method, but I prefer model.fit(). Is there a way to pass Dataset to x and y parameters of model.fit()?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of Community, I am providing the @Niel_Eenterm solution here

> I've found a solution which now solves my problem and that is to
> implement a fully custom training loop using tf.GradientTape():
>
> ```
> @tf.function
> def train_step(x, y):
>     with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
>         # Here you pass arguments in your desired way
>         logits = model((x,y), training=True)
>         loss_value = loss_fn(y, logits)
>     grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
>     opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
>     train_acc_metric.update_state(y, logits)
>     return loss_value
>
> # Prepare the loss function
> loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
>
> # Prepare the metrics.
> train_acc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
> val_acc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
>
> for epoch in range(epochs):
>     epoch_losses = []
>     for img, label in zip(trainX, trainY):
>         loss_value = train_step(img, label)
>         epoch_losses.append(loss_value.numpy())
>     
>     # Display metrics at the end of each epoch.
>     train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
>     train_epoch_loss = np.mean(epoch_losses)
>     
>     # Reset training metrics at the end of each epoch
>     train_acc_metric.reset_states()
> ```